# A 4.00 L sample of gas is cooled from 67 °C to a temperature at which its volume is 2.60 L

Tags: gas-laws

A $4~\mathrm{L}$ sample of gas is cooled from $67~\mathrm{°C}$ to a temperature at which its volume is $2.6~\mathrm{L}$. What is this new temperature? Assume no change in pressure of the gas.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use Ideal gas equation:

> $$\large PV=nRT$$

Given pressure is constant, can you tell the final temperature from this relation?

Comment: Then $\frac{V_\text{1}}{V_\text{2}} = \frac{T_\text{1}}{T_\text{2}}$ can be derived using the relation given by @ADG